# How to create a bitmap image programmatically when its source is an image with Build Action = Resource?

Tags: silverlight, uri, bitmapimage

How to create a bitmap image programmatically when its source is an image with Build Action = Resource?

When I try the following I get an invalid URI exception :(

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Images/MyImage.png"));
```

I'm using silverlight 4 and this code is inside one of the many projects of my solution (it's a silverlight class library and not the silverlight application).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Images/MyImage.png"));
```

should be:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Images/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

`Images/MyImage.png` also assumes your image is located inside a folder called `Images`.

Comment: hello david it is not working for me..i am using .net 4.5 is thr any package that has to be installed .what i want is to set a bitapimage from a image that  is in assets folder.

Comment: you have to also check the properties of the image entry in the solution explorer to be set to "Resource" and "Do not copy"

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = new ImageInline(new Uri("/BF.SilverlightClient;component/Views/Reports/ChartLegendBar.png", UriKind.Relative))
            { Width = 200, Height = 25};
```

Comment: what is ImageInline class? I can only find an InlineImage in Telerik documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radrichtextbox/document-elements/features-inlineimage.html